How do the later rupa kalapas get qualities of their before rupa kalapas by birth
when a object made with rupa kalapas is given a force, heated or travelling at a constant speed, how do the next generations of the same rupa kalapas get those qualities(forces, heat, speed ,etc..)by their birth (at uthpada)..(is this happening due to a pratyaya, please be kind to mention it  )
